# Margins around slideshow not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, slideshow

I'm having trouble with defining margins around a slideshow.
They're simply not being shown. Before the slideshow it was just one static image with margins.
So I suspect the slideshow is involved somehow. Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is part of the code:

```
    <div class="cnts"><div style="float:right"; "margin-left:15px; margin-right:5px; margin-top:10px;">
<div class="box_skitter box_skitter_normal">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#directionTop"><img src="images/slideshow/27112013836_k.jpg" class="directionTop" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>Wachtkamer</p></div></li>
                <li><a href="#directionBottom"><img src="images/slideshow/slide_05122013856.jpg" class="directionBottom" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>Hoek</p></div></li>
<li><a href="#directionRight"><img src="images/slideshow/slide_07122013861.jpg" class="directionRight"/></a><div class="label_text"><p>Behandelstoel</p></div></li></ul></div></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`style="float:right"; "margin-left:15px; margin-right:5px; margin-top:10px;"`

should be

`style="float:right;margin-left:15px; margin-right:5px; margin-top:10px;"`

You've ended the `style attr` with a `"` after `right`, so the `margins` aren't attached to the `style attr`